# Setting up tether-drop to work with angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24

Tags: angular-cli, tether

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to setup tether-drop with my angular 2 app created with angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.24.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new project with the angular-cli.

   - `ng new tester --skip-git`
2. Follow the angular-cli instructions for installing third party library:

   - `npm install tether-drop --save`
   - `npm install @types/tether-drop --save`
3. At this point I fully expect to be able to use the following line in app.component.ts

   - `import { Drop } from 'tether-drop';`

But when I `ng serve` the result is this error:

- `ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
  Module build failed: Error: D:/Visual Studio Code/tester/src/app/app.component.ts (3,10): Module '"D:/Visual Studio Code/tester/node_modules/@types/tether-drop/index"' has no exported member 'Drop'.)
  at _checkDiagnostics (D:\Visual Studio Code\tester\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:116:15)
  at D:\Visual Studio Code\tester\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\loader.js:141:17
  @ ./src/app/app.module.ts 14:0-47
  @ ./src/main.ts
  @ multi main`

I have struggled mightily with integrating third party libraries into angular-cli generated projects (webpack).  I managed to get some of them working but a solution for this one is alluding me.

Can someone please enlighten me and remove this burden of ignorance from me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to change your import to:

```
import * as Drop from 'tether-drop';
```

And then you can use it as per the README:

```
const dropInstance = new Drop({
  /* options here */
});
```

Comment: This is the answer.  But I need to add a comment.  Once tether-drop was working I started adding back other libraries I am using.  In particular Bootstrap 4.  Bootstrap 4 relies on tether.js for tooltip and popover.  So if you follow the Bootstrap instructions for angular-cli you eventually add the appropriate references to tether.js and bootstrap.js to anglat-cli.json.  Once you do this it will break tether-drop.  Something about adding tether.js to the angular-cli.json scripts property breaks tether-drop.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add it to `scripts` if you import it. Usually `scripts` are for the scripts that don't work well with imports in TypeScript, and/or the Webpack processing they get included into when imported. So, `import` and `angular-cli.json` `scripts` are mutually exclusive.